# sysproperty set to value "${value}" when no property is passed to target

Tags: ant

I am executing a target with paramters as `Dcolor=red`.I am using this property value to set system property as

```
<sysproperty key="COLOR" value="${color}" />
```

If not passing any parameter named `-Dcolor`, when fetching key `COLOR` as `System.getProperty("COLOR")` is returning `${color}`.

Is this correct behavior. How to handle such scenario ie. setting COLOR as null if no parameter names color is passed.

Please let me know if I am missing basics here. Resource link will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

That's crazy, the evaluation of the properties is done by the PropertyHelper class of the ant. But based on the source code, the returned value should be null, but it's not.
The [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) says the ant tries to evaluate it, but it doesn't state what happens if the evalutation is unsuccessful.

You can set a default value by predefining the property.

```
<property name="COLOR" value="defaultColor" />
```

But this will never set value null.

And finally after a long search, I found out that using [syspropertyset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) instead of sysproperty, will return nulls.

This is a working example:

```
    <propertyset id="java.props">
        <propertyref name="test.property"/>
      </propertyset> 
    <java>
            <syspropertyset refid="java.props"/>
  </java>
```

If you get the test.property, it will return null.